# Xubuntu not automatically suspending after idle anymore

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, xfce

When I first installed Xubuntu on my system, it would automatically suspend after the set idle period no problem.  But I seem to have changed something and its no longer working.

I've checked the usual suspects, first and foremost being that I have actually set it properly in xfce4-power-manager which I think I do:

[image: Xfce Power Manager Settings]

When I run `systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block` I get the following:

```
WHO                 UID  USER      PID  COMM            WHAT                                                                       WHY                                      MODE
xfce4-power-manager 1000 doctor_ew 1192 xfce4-power-man handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch xfce4-power-manager handles these events block
xfce4-power-manager 1000 doctor_ew 1071 xfce4-screensav idle                                                                       Inhibit requested                        block

2 inhibitors listed.
```

But I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be seeing that or not.  Are there any other troubleshooting steps anyone can recommend, I'm not sure what else I could check at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same inhibitor displayed when enabling the "presentation mode" of the power managment widget in my dashboard. You may have activated that.

[image]

Comment: THAT WAS IT.  I actually had to enable that widget just to check, so I have no idea how it got accidentally toggled, but sure enough Presentation Mode was enabled. Thank you very much for posting, I never found any mention of that in my research.

Answer (score 0):

The first inhibitor is ok, but the second should not be there.
If I check `ps ax | grep screen` I get:

```
1135 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/xfce4-screensaver --no-daemon
```

So our configurations must differ. I've setup my power manager the same way you do.
The `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` should be disabled throughout all entries:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

This has been discussed [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2070432)

Comment: This is my home gaming server, so I've got the screensaver completely disabled, as well as logind.conf with all disabled.  I tried killing the unused screensaver process, but it still hasn't gone to sleep.  I know its wrong but I think I'm going to try killing the power manager too.  No inhibitors == sleep right?  If that works at least I can narrow down my troubleshooting.  Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Yes, the screensaver may not inhibit the power manager. If it helps, you could accept my answer

Comment: Sorry forgot to reply, I tried getting rid of the screensaver inhibitor and its still awake.  I'm still digging into it and I'll keep updating this question if I find anything